# splitting a string with some kind of whitespace

Tags: php

I've got the following code:

```
$output2 = 'text&NewLine;&NewLine;more text&NewLine;&NewLine;ja';
$explode = explode('&NewLine;&NewLine;', $output);
```

This works fine and the `$explode` array prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => meer text
    [2] => ja
)
```

However, the following code doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it:

```
$output = 'text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;more text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;ja';

$explode = explode('&NewLine;&NewLine;', $output);
```

The `$explode` array prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    &NewLine;
    &NewLine;  //more text
    &NewLine;
    &NewLine;ja
)
```

This might seem like a weird question. But the first example is a test I made manually. But the second example is what is actually returned from the database.

Comment: You probably need to split by `"&NewLine;\n&NewLine;"` (note the double quotes and the `\n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split your string:

```
<?php
$output = 'text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;more text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;ja';

$explode = preg_split('/(&NewLine;|(\r\n|\r|\n))+/', $output, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/KU0v9t (*ideone*) or https://eval.in/887393 (*eval.in*)

---

The following solution to split on double `&NewLine;`:

```
$output = 'text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;more text
&NewLine;
&NewLine;ja
&NewLine;nein';

$explode = preg_split('/(\r\n|\r|\n)*(&NewLine;(\r\n|\r|\n)*){2}/', $output, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/0txh5O

Comment: I have doubt on this site,  Giving wrong result : https://eval.in/887381

Comment: This indeed worked, thanks. However, with the actual database output it prints the following:


Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => more text
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => ja
)

Comment: @user2486 that's the same result i'm getting.

Comment: Yes I think its a fault of eval.in

Comment: see update: the problem was the spaces (by my formatting) and the new line with `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Thank you so much, i would like to ask one more question. How can i make sure it only splits when a double new line is added? It now split for every new line, but i would like to have it split for every 2 new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one line in your code `$output =str_replace("\r\n","",$output );` to combine all string in one line so that it would like your first example.

```
$output =str_replace("\r\n","",$output );
$explode = explode('&NewLine;&NewLine;', $output);
print_r($explode);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/887371

Answer (score 0):

```
$explode = preg_split('/&NewLine;\s*&NewLine;/', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

normalize your string by removing all new line like chars:

```
$output = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$output));
```

then explode it.

Answer (score 0):

As User2486 says, the problem is that there are some hidden characters you are not watching like \n and \r

In your first example you have

```
'text&NewLine;&NewLine;more text&NewLine;&NewLine;ja'
```

and in the second

```
'text\r\n&NewLine;\r\n&NewLine;more text\r\n&NewLine;\r\n&NewLine;ja'
```